# Insert value into a text box which is inside an echo statement

Tags: php, variables, input, echo

I have this code basis:

```
echo '<input required  type = "text" name = "subject1" value="XXX" />';
```

However, I would like XXX to be a variable, I have searched this online, but all the things that one of the discussions says is to do this:

```
value=\"$firstName\"
```

or

```
value='$firstName'
```

I have tried both of these, but they don't work, and I was hoping that someone could help me with this problem, basically, what I want is to be able to asign the value of a text edit to a variable in php, but when the text edit itself, is embedded in an echo, nothing seems to work.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Concatenation is a pretty easy way to go about this:

```
echo '<input required  type = "text" name = "subject1" value="' . $foo . '" />'
```

edit: Those spaces around the concatenation .'s (`. $foo .`) aren't required - I just add them fore readability.

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem is you are using single quotes, so variables are not rendered automatically... you can concat with `.` like this:

```
echo 'some text' . $variable . 'some more text';
```

Comment: so, should I generally use the double quotes?

Comment: @JBellamy It's both a matter of taste and dependent on what you're doing. If you have anything relatively complex to do, mixing strings with variables, you should really look into [sprintf()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php). Otherwise you'll rarely find a case where concatenation or double quotes are significantly superior to each other. Double quotes are nice in cases such as `echo "My name is $name, I'm $age years old!";`, but when strings contain a lot of double quotes already, I find it gets ugly.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo '<input required type="text" name = "subject1 value="<?php echo $value; ?>" />';
```

acutally you don't need the php echo ....  stuff....  /* brain not engaged */